# How to add a form to a form?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a form below a form when I click the button. Code so far:

```
<form class="a" action="" method="" > 
  product:<input type="text">
  price:<input type="text">
</form>
<div class="b"> </div>
<button class="c"> add </button>
```

jquery:

```
  $('.c').on('click', function(){
    $('.a').insertAfter($('.b'))
  });
```

I tried with append but it is not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `clone()` to copy the first form and then use append() to put it into the other container

```
$('.c').on('click', function(){
    var $clone = $('.a:first').clone();
    // clear all values in clone
    $clone.find(':input').val('');
    $('.b').append( $clone );    
});
```

The current approach you are using is simply going to move the existing one

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h3ad3b6c/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You forgot the dot in front of b.</strike>

```
$('.a').insertAfter($('.b'))
```

```
$('.c').on('click', function(){
    $('.a').appendTo($('.b'));
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/t5sx2h4v/1/

And here is how you can append a new form.

```
$('.c').on('click', function(){
    $('<form><input type="text"/></form>').appendTo($('.b'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5sx2h4v/2/

Comment: Sorry. Something I missed out when I wrote the code here. Still unable to make the form appear.

Comment: all this does is move the form, it doesn't add one

Comment: You should be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Is the form already part of the DOM?